# Проблема вывода данных с помощью fetchall sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite3

Хочу вывести объединенные данные таблицы с помощью fetchall, а он ничего не выводит, не понимаю в чем проблема, помогите пожалуйста.

Сам код:

```
import sqlite3 as sq3

con = sq3.connect('test.db')
cursor = con.cursor()

cursor.execute("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Friend(
    name TEXT not NULL,
    age INTEGER)
""")

cursor.execute("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Other(
    addres TEXT not NULL,
    email TEXT not NULL)
""")

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Friend (name, age) VALUES (?, ?)", ("Petr", 23))
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Friend (name, age) VALUES (?, ?)", ("Ivan", 19))
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Friend (name, age) VALUES (?, ?)", ("Kostya", 32))

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Other (addres, email) VALUES (?, ?)", ("ul Kapitalnaya", "fdkjgkf@gmail.com"))
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Other (addres, email) VALUES (?, ?)", ("ul Lenina", "ljglj@gmail.com"))
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Other (addres, email) VALUES (?, ?)", ("ul Komunisticheskiy", "wpost@gmail.com"))
con.commit()

sel = cursor.execute('''
SELECT Friend.name, Other.addres
FROM Friend JOIN Other
ON Friend.name = Other.addres
''')

rows = sel.fetchall()
for i in rows:
    print(i)
```

Comment: `ON Friend.name = Other.addres` - имена и адреса не совпадают, поэтому ничего не выводится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы вывести объединенные данные из 2 таблиц, их нужно связать внутренним и внешним ключами.

```
cursor.execute("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Friend(
    id      INTEGER     PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name    TEXT        not NULL,
    age     INTEGER
)
""")
```

`PRIMARY KEY` является уникальным ключом для каждой записи в таблице `Friend`.

`AUTOINCREMENT` автоматически прибавляет единицу к каждой следующей записи в таблице.

Теперь нужно привязать записи таблицы `Other` к записям `Friend`. Связка происходит путем указания внешнего ключа `FOREIGN KEY` для записей в `Other`, который является первичным ключом для каждой записи в `Friend`:

```
cursor.execute("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Other(
    id              INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    friend_id       INTEGER,
    addres          TEXT not NULL,
    email           TEXT not NULL,
    
    FOREIGN KEY (friend_id) REFERENCES Friends (id)
)
""")
```

Теперь, добавляя записи во вторую таблицу, указываем 3 поля:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Other (friend_id, addres, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (1, "ul Kapitalnaya", "fdkjgkf@gmail.com"))
```

Запрос на объединение данных из таблиц, следующий:

```
sel = cursor.execute('''
SELECT name, addres
FROM Friend JOIN Other
ON Friend.id = Other.friend_id
''')
```

**Весь код получается такой:**

```
import sqlite3 as sq3

con = sq3.connect('test.db')
cursor = con.cursor()

cursor.execute("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Friend(
    id      INTEGER     PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name    TEXT        not NULL,
    age     INTEGER
)
""")

cursor.execute("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Other(
    id              INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    friend_id       INTEGER,
    addres          TEXT not NULL,
    email           TEXT not NULL,
    
    FOREIGN KEY (friend_id) REFERENCES Friends (id)
)
""")

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Friend (name, age) VALUES (?, ?)", ("Petr", 23))
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Friend (name, age) VALUES (?, ?)", ("Ivan", 19))
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Friend (name, age) VALUES (?, ?)", ("Kostya", 32))

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Other (friend_id, addres, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (1, "ul Kapitalnaya", "fdkjgkf@gmail.com"))
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Other (friend_id, addres, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (2, "ul Lenina", "ljglj@gmail.com"))
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Other (friend_id, addres, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (3, "ul Komunisticheskiy", "wpost@gmail.com"))
con.commit()

sel = cursor.execute('''
SELECT name, addres
FROM Friend JOIN Other
ON Friend.id = Other.friend_id
''')


rows = sel.fetchall()
for item in rows:
  print(item[0], item[1])
```

Comment: Ответ очень хороший. Но если используется `AUTOINCREMENT`, то хорошо бы получать сгенерированные айдишники после вставки (например, с помощью [RETURNING](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_returning.html)). / А если значения `friend_id` вставляются несгенерированные, то убрать автоинкремент и в таблицу `Friend` тоже вручную вставлять эти же `id`.

Comment: Да, с RETURNING и в правду удобнее. На скорую руку написал ;)

Comment: Спасибо!! Помогло